# eclipse pydev debug unable - can't view the step into option

Tags: python, pydev

I'm using the pydev debugger but I can't see the step-into option to navigate through the debugger.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you look under "Customize Perspective..." in the Window > Perspective menu, you should have an option for Debug.  You can expand this to find the options for Step Into / Over / etc.  It appears that those have been disabled.

Optionally, under that same menu, you can choose to "Reset Perspective..." to restore the defaults which *should* bring those controls back as well.